# Indistinguishability of two random matrices

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Define $X_n$ and $X_n'$ be two random matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ (with unknown distributions).

All we know their relative norms is pretty small:
$$
\frac{\|X_n - X_n'\|_2}{\|X_n\|_2}\in O(1/n) \; \; \; \; a.s., 
$$
for some parameter $n$. $n$ is a parameter controls the random sampling of $X$ and $X'$ (The bigger $n$ is, the closer $X$ and $X'$ are, as denoted by the above inequality).

Define an integrable function $f$: 
$$
f: \mathbb{R}^{d \times d} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}
$$

**Prove that:** for any choice of $f$ and any $\delta > 0$, $\exists n_0$, such that for any $n \geq n_0$:

$$
\mathbb{P}(f(X_n) = f(X_n')) \geq 1-\delta
$$

Feel free to make assumptions on the function class $f$ to make the above statement happen.

Comment: Is $O(1/n)$ almost sure or in probability?

Comment: Correct. Updated it.

Comment: Are we talking about a sequence of distributions of $X$ indexed by $n$?

Comment: @Vim Sorry about the confusion. $n$ is a parameter controls the random sampling of $X$ and $X'$. The bigger $n$ is, the closer $X$ and $X'$ are.

Comment: so $n$ actually controls the distribution of $X$, or $X'$?

Comment: That is correct. But we don't know their exact distribution.

Comment: you don't have to know what they are but you can use $X_n$ instead of $X$ to emphasise that there's actually a *sequence* of distributions.

Comment: That's a good point. I will update it.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2897833/14578, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/41459/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: As I pointed out in cstheory, this is not true. Forget about matrices, take the case $d=1$. Take $X_n$ uniform in $[1 - 1/n, 1]$ and $X'_n$  uniform in $[1, 1+1/n]$ and $f(X)$ equals $1$ if $X < 1$.

Comment: @SashoNikolov what assumptions I can make on the distribution of $X_n$ and $X'_n$ such I don't fall in such corner cases?